# sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream, request: "POST

Tags: javascript, nginx, meteor, amazon-ec2, passenger

I'm having issue when uploading file on production using meteor with nginx + passenger. I'm also using [meteor files](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) for uploading files. it worked great in development but i can't upload files in production. i got and error in browser console:

`POST http://my-url/ net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)`

i found error in my passenger log file saying **Not keep-aliving application session connection because application did not allow it** here is the log:

`[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:183 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing new chunk
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:123 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: chunk size determined: 982 bytes
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:162 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing 982 of 982 bytesof remaining chunk data; 0 now remaining
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:1416 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] Feeding 982 bytes
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:486 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] pushBuffer() completed: nbuffers = 1, bytesBuffered = 982
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:554 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] Reader: reading next
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:586 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] Reader: found buffer, 982 bytes
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:493 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] popBuffer() completed: nbuffers = 0,bytesBuffered = 0
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:594 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] Reader: feeding buffer, 982 bytes
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:554 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] Reader: reading next
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:561 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] Reader: no more buffers. Transitioning to RS_INACTIVE
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:539 ]: [FBC 0x7f71e801b670] Calling dataFlushedCallback
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:64 ]: [Client 2-63] Event: onAppSourceData
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2194 2500/Ta age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:206 ]: [Client 2-63] Processing 7 bytes of application data: "\r\n0\r\n\r\n"
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:248 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: done parsing a chunk
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:183 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing new chunk
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:123 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: chunk size determined: 0bytes
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:162 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing 0 of 0 bytes of remaining chunk data; 0 now remaining
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:164 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: end chunk detected
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:267 ]: [Client 63] ChunkedBodyParser: end chunk reached
[ D2 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:224 ]: [Client 2-63] End of application response body reached
[ D2 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:1077 ]: [Client 2-63] Not keep-aliving application sessionconnection because application did not allow it
[ D3 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta age/Cor/App/Socket.h:201 ]: Socket unix:/tmp/passenger.toEIX2t/apps.s/node.1si9u5: connection not checked back into connection pool. There are now 2 connections in total
[ D2 2018-09-27 16:53:44.2195 2500/Ta age/Cor/App/Gro/SessionManagement.cpp:150 ]: Session closed for process (pid=2519, group=/var/www/hmn/bundle (production))`

- Meteor 1.6.1
- Meteor-Files 1.9.11
- Ubuntu 16.04
- nginx 1.14.0
- passenger 5.3.5
- AWS

this is my nginx config file

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    # tcp_nopush     on;
    # tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length 500;
    gzip_types    text/plain text/xml text/css
                  text/comma-separated-values
                  text/javascript
                  application/x-javascript
                  application/atom+xml;

    include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }

    // sites-enabled/* file
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server{
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/mydomain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/mydomain.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_sticky_sessions on;
        root /var/www/my_app/bundle/public;
        passenger_app_type node;
        passenger_startup_file main.js;
        passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://some_shard_urls;
        passenger_env_var ROOT_URL https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        passenger_env_var MONGO_OPLOG_URL: mongodb://some_shard_urls;
        keepalive_timeout  1000;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GC$
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
        access_log  /var/log/my_app/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/my_app/error.log;

        proxy_send_timeout 60s;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                client_max_body_size 100M;
                if ($uri != '/') {
                    expires 30d;
                }
                break;
        }
}
```

I'm using aws S3 to hosting the file and meteor files has feature to integrate with s3. here is my sample code:

```
 const ProductAssets = new FilesCollection({
    debug: false,
    collectionName: 'collection_name',
    allowClientCode: false,
    storagePath: './products',
    permissions: 0777,
    // debug: true,
    chunkSize: 'dynamic',
    parentDirPermissions: 0777,
    onBeforeUpload: function(file) {
        if (/png|jpe?g/i.test(file.extension)) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    onAfterUpload(fileRef) {
        Meteor.call('upload.to.s3', fileRef)
    },
});

// upload to s3 method
'upload.to.s3': function(fileRef) {
    _.each(fileRef.versions, async (vRef, version) => {
        const filePath = 'products/' + fileRef._id + '/' + version + '-' + fileRef._id + '.' + fileRef.extension;
        await s3.putObject({
            // ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
            StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: filePath,
            Body: fs.createReadStream(vRef.path),
            ContentType: vRef.type
        }, (error, data) => {
            bound(() => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                } else {
                    // Update FilesCollection with link to the file at AWS
                    const upd = { $set: {} };
                    upd['$set']['versions.' + version + '.meta.pipePath'] = filePath;

                    ProductAssets.collection.update({
                        _id: fileRef._id
                    }, upd, (updError) => {
                        if (updError) {
                            console.error(updError);
                        } else {
                            // Unlink original files from FS after successful upload to AWS:S3
                            ProductAssets.unlink(ProductAssets.collection.findOne(fileRef._id), version);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    })
},
```

on side note, files that is being uploaded doesn't saved into database and s3 on production. on development, the files is saved and uploaded to s3 properly

anybody know how to fix it and explain what is wrong? thank you!

Comment: Meteor files can have multiple forms of saving the file on your backend, for example Filesystem, CollectionFS, GridFS, AWS S3 etc. Which one are you exactly using? Can you also please add the `FilesCollection` code related to the files you want to upload? Edit: Please also add your nginx config. This gave me some headaches with files in the past, too.

Comment: i'm using S3 to hosting our files. i edited my question with my nginx config and `FilesCollection` sample code @Jankapunkt

Comment: @Jankapunkt sorry can you help me please?

Comment: This is really hard to find a bug in a production app of others without access to it. I can only ask you to try the same with the AutoForm files gridFs and see if the same issue occurs there or not. If it occurs there I can try to replicate as I have no s3 Account anymore.